# jQuery getJSON won't work on cross domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, jsonp, getjson

I'm trying to use google maps' REST api to convert an typed in adress to coordinates. To do so I use jQuery's getJSON function as it uses a native JSONP call.

Though it won't work, it just doesn't get to success, so the alert is never called.

```
$("#makeCords").click(function(){
    straat = $('#straat').val();
    stad = $('#Stad').val();
    land = $('#Country').val();
    if(straat == "" || stad == "" || land == ""){
        alert("Onvoldoende gegevens! Vul straat, stad en land aan voor het gebruik van de ´bereken coordinaten´ functie.");
    }else{
        $.getJSON("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?callback=?",
        {
            adress: straat +", " + stad +", " + land,
            sensor: "false"
        },
          function(data) {
              alert(data);
          });
    }
});
```

Comment: What happens if you use the URL `http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json`?

Comment: adress was a type indeed. But still, google will respond with an error also in json format. So the alert should still be executed. It is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Google Maps Geocoding API does not support JSON-P; it will ignore your `callback` parameter, thus cross-domain JSON-P won't work.

You should use **official Google Maps Javascript library** instead. Internally the library does use JSON-P to pass the information (since it's *almost* the only way to do cross-domain requests), but that URL is reserved to official library use only.

Comment: I just found out, using Chrome Javascript console, that the JSON data is received but gives the following error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`

Does this mean it does work but somehow the source of the error is somewhere else or should I just use the Google maps javascript library anyway?

Comment: You should use the JS library supplied anyway.

Comment: Not sure but getJSON might be expecting something like `jQuery15204934664060250754_1309622592360({/*json data*/})`, instead it gets `{/*json data*/}`

Comment: @Salman That's what I meant the URL does not support JSON-P, since it ignores the function name specified in `callback`.

Answer (score 0):

try adding **&format=json** to your get jason url and chaneg &callback=? to **&jsoncallback=?**

Comment: The URI is ok by now, google is returning nice and clean json, but I know that because I pasted the URI in my browser. both jQuery's ajax and getJSON functions won't execute the success function.

Answer (score 0):

Try jquery jsonp:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "http://url",
   dataType: "jsonp" ,
   success: function (data) {

   }
});
```

Comment: Still doesn't get to the success function.

Answer (score -2):

Isn't it a kind of security that javascript (in this case jquery) won't ever get or post data outside it's own domain (at least as far as I know javascript is not allowed to `post` or `get` cross domains)? You could use a local php script gathering the json information from the google server by curl and send your get-query to this local script. I would give this workaround a try...

Another way would be to use the google maps api for javascript. You could use the gecoding functions from that api to retrieve the latitude and longitude from a given address. So you wouldn't need to make any gets or posts...

Comment: Isn't JSONP actually the way to do requests to other servers? I can't use php curl because my client's hosting provider doesn't allow it :(.

Comment: when you use getJSON with callback= the request becomes a JSONP request which does work cross-domain. This should have been a comment, not an answer -1

Comment: As I allready said. I am pretty sure it is a security issue. Javascript doesn't allow cross domain gets or posts. As your provider denies using curl you can still use the google maps api...

Comment: You're incorrect Marco, you can use JSONP to make cross-domain requests. With jQuery, you just need to set `dataType: "jsonp"` and that takes care of it.