# use $.getJSON get data from google's geocode api, return 'Uncaught SyntaxError'

Tags: jquery, json, google-maps, geocode

i got a "**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :**"  error.

why and how to handle this error?

thanks!

```
$.getJSON("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=39.971277199999996,116.4864269&language=zh-CN&sensor=false&callback=?");
```

you can open this page and see console: http://jsbin.com/ugoraw/1

the return json like this,

```
{
   "results" : [
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "16号",
               "short_name" : "16号",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "将台西路",
               "short_name" : "将台西路",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            ... ...
```

Comment: You get the error message text right in the middle of the JSON string? In a string generated by Google?

Comment: thanks attention. here is a demo: http://jsbin.com/ugoraw/1/edit

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery getJSON won't work on cross domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557864/jquery-getjson-wont-work-on-cross-domain)

Answer (score 1):

The question mark is causing the problem.

You need to change the `?` to a function:

```
$(function(){
  $.getJSON("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=39.971277199999996,116.4864269&language=zh-CN&sensor=false&callback=handleMaps");

  function handleMaps(data) {
        alert("working");
  }

});
```

Note you won't be allowed do this in jsbin because of access control restrictions.

I would also recommend reading the following question and answers:
[jQuery and Google Maps json response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5659663/jquery-and-google-maps-json-response)